# DXA Component Template Metadata schema documentation

Tags: dxa

I cannot find the documentation for the DXA Component Template Metadata to explain what each field is for and how it relates to the .net MVC Site.

I have googled, tried docs.rws.com, the community site and knowledge base.

I remember that there was some basic "how to configure an Area" on the "SDL Developer Course" some years ago but can't find a definitive guide.
[image: Component Template Metadata]

Answer (score 2):

Select the “General” tab:

- Add the “Component Template Metadata” schema to the “Metadata
  Schema” field:
- Enter an “Entity View Name” using the format:“ModuleName:ViewName”

[image]